# Flutter AppLifecycleState Changes and The Time Between Being Killed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to figure out the best way to save app state data (several form entries) to local storage when a user leaves the app or locks their screen. This is to avoid data being lost if the app is killed because of low device memory.

I am currently using the WidgetsBindingObserver mixin, and am successfully printing some test statements to console before the app is killed. However, I am trying to figure out to what extend code could be executed before the AppLifecycleState. It is after the app becomes paused that I am writing to local memory, but I am worried that it may not always fully execute before being killed.

I am trying to write a fair amount of data, and would prefer to do it only once when the app changes to a volatile state (paused, or inactive) rather than when each data entry from the user is captured.

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it was impossible to complete an asynchronous call before the app process, and the call, was destroyed. I had to find another way to save the data so that it was not lost when the app was killed by the OS.

To fix this I had to implement a local data store using Hive (https://pub.dev/packages/hive). The data inputted to the app is saved after each entry, and then loaded back into the app state if a user chooses to restore the data that was lost.

The Flutter State Restoration improvements were not able to capture the use case I was dealing with, as their widget state restoration does not adequately support states contained in providers and multiple nested widgets.